# Change bar color in bar chart based on job status in Splunk Dashboard

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard, splunk-formula

Change bar color in bar chart based on job status.

I get below messages:

```html
Job XYZ Finished in 275 seconds
Job XYZ Finished with errors in 454 seconds
Job XYZ Finished in 473 seconds
```

[image]

I tried different way but it's not working out, Can anyone help on it? Thank

```
index=stg_index "Job Finished in" OR "Job Finished with errors in" 
| rex "in (?<Num>[^\s]+) seconds" 
| timechart values(Num) as ExecutionTime span=60min 
| sort _time
```

Comment: Can you share your SPL please?

Comment: Splunk link? Its not possible. I updated question with search query.

Comment: I meant the search query, thanks!

When you say "the bar should be RED if job fails", do you mean the bar should be red if the log contains the "Finished with errors" text?

Comment: yes, the bar should be red if the log contains the "Finished with errors" text and Green when if the log contains the "Finished in" text. And need execution time on bar 454.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I posted an answer for you to try.

Comment: btw - you don't need to `| sort _time` after your `timechart` - `timechart` does that already :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to split the job statuses into different series (e.g. `failed` and `ok`). Here is a run anywhere example based off your initial search:

```
| makeresults
| eval sample = "Job XYZ Finished in 275 seconds|Job XYZ Finished with errors in 454 seconds|Job XYZ Finished in 473 seconds"
| makemv sample delim="|"
| mvexpand sample
| eval _time = _time - random() / 100000
| rename sample as _raw
| rex "in (?<exec_time>[^\s]+) seconds"
| rex "Finished with (?<status>error)"
| fillnull value="ok" status
| timechart span=60min max(exec_time) as ExecutionTime by status
```

Here is a specific adaptation of your initial search:

```
index=stg_index "Job Finished in" OR "Job Finished with errors in"
| rex "in (?<Num>[^\s]+) seconds"
| rex "Finished with (?<status>error)"
| fillnull value="ok" status
| timechart span=60min values(Num) as ExecutionTime by status
```

By default Splunk will give each series a different colour. If you specifically want it to be red then you'll need to save your search in a dashboard. To add specific colours to a simple XML dashboard then you can add the following tag to the XML, here is a red and green example:

```xml
<option name="charting.fieldColors">{"failed":#FF0000,"ok":#007840}</option>
```

Also FYI, using `values(Num)` in a timechart might cause a particular entry to be hidden if two or more events reside in the same span within the same series. Consider using max(Num), min(Num) or avg(Num) depending on the context of your dashboard.

Comment: Is any solution for "values(Num)" if two or more events resides in same span?

Comment: Consider using max(Num), min(Num) or avg(Num) depending on the context of your dashboard.